# how to plot data in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, plot, graph

I've been struggling to plot some real time data, checked a few libraries including graphview and plotly and etc. but I couldn't get any of them to work is there any way to plot some real time data using canvas without the use of 3rd party libraries?
working on this app:

https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Toolbox

which has no layout for the above libraries to work(I'm doing this project just to get it done and I'm not a kotlin dev correct me if I'm wrong please)
, thanks!

Comment: "is there any way to plot some real time data using canvas without the use of 3rd party libraries" -- you can draw lines and arcs and stuff on a `Canvas` in a custom `View` (or in a composable).

Comment: Create a custom `View`, override `onDraw` and use the drawing tools to plot your data on the `Canvas` - you'll have to work out where to draw based on the View's width and height. Call `invalidate()` at the end of `onDraw()` to make it redraw on the next frame, so you can plot the current data in as "real-time" as you can get (unless you want your data source to invalidate the view whenever it gets new data)